# Amazon AWS connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos

I'm novice in AWS and I made awful mistake.
I changed `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and of course, I cannot connect to my virtual machine (Cent OS 6). Is there some way to connect from web interface for changing back `ifcfg-eth0`?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try shutting down and restarting the instance from the AWS control panel or CLI tools.  As part of that process AWS may assign a new IP address to the host, so it may repair what you did to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.  Make sure you try to connect to the new IP address that's assigned to the host after you restart it.

If that doesn't work then you may need to bite the bullet and launch a new instance.